# Create array class objects

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, code-translation

I want to do something that I've done before in Java, but *need* to do in C#.

The code in Java that do would be similar to:

```
public Class<? extends Thing>[] classes = new Class<? extends Thing>[3] {
    OneThing.class,
    AnotherThing.class
    YetAnotherThing.class
    // etc.
}
```

Is this possible in C# in any way?  Ultimately what I'm trying to do is to have an array of classes representing types of items.  Then this array is used to check against the type of the item to produce a boolean value representing if the item has a superclass of the index in the array.  To clarify, I'm checking to see if the class of the instance of a `Thing` is also an instance of `OneThing`, `AnotherThing`, etc.

What matters is that I'm trying to create an array not of a regular object like `Random`, but of whatever C#'s counterpart of the Java `Class` class is.

Comment: If I remember my Java correctly (and I might not), you are trying to declare an array of _type_ instances where each type inherits the base type `Thing`. Correct? If so, then I don't think C#'s generic constraint system allows for that. I.e. it can constrain a type based on what it actually inherits, but it can't constraint an _instance_ of a `Type` to accomplish the same. You'd have to implement something that enforces that at run-time instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What I'm trying to do is create an array of classes where each class is a child of `Thing`.  I'm checking to see if the actual class of the object (which much be in some way a `Thing`) also happens to be a child of the class specified by the index that is also passed to the function (not shown).

Comment: Okay, so I did understand correctly. In that case, I think the closest you can come is a custom wrapper class with a "where T : Type" constraint, and then internally enforces the constraint of T being a `Type` instance representing an actual type that inherits `Thing`. I'd post an example as an answer, but I'd rather not discourage the C# generics experts from weighing in. I'll happily do that in 12-24 hours, if no one else has yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Java where `Class<T>` is generic on the type represented by the class, `System.Type` objects of C# are not generic at all. You can create an array of them as follows:

```
Type[] classes = new[] {
    typeof(OneThing)
,   typeof(AnotherThing)
,   typeof(ThirdThing)
};
```

However, the compiler is unable to enforce the check that the classes derive from or implement a particular base or an interface. You should be able to perform your checks without this restriction, though:

```
var obj = ... // This is your object
var res = classes.Select((t, i) => new {t, i}).FirstOrDefault(p => p.t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(obj)));
if (res != 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} assignable from {1} is found at {2}.", res.t, typeof(obj), res.i);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Type {0} is not found in the array.", typeof(obj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# we have `System.Type` you can create a collection of it and keep type of all classes in it. Then you can apply your rules. `Type` is used in c# for reflection purposes. Check c# reflection for more. Here is a simple code demonstrating what you asked for. I have tried to keep it really simple and not to mix other c# concepts so that it will be easier for someone new to c# to understand.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Program
{
    static List<Type> list = new List<Type>();

    static void Main()
    {

        list.Add(typeof(A));
        C c = new C();
        D d = new D();

        Check(c);
        Check(d);

    }

    static void Check(Object toBeChecked){

        foreach (Type t in list)
        {
            if(t.IsAssignableFrom(toBeChecked.GetType())){
                System.Console.WriteLine("Yes it is type of");
                return;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("No it is not type of");
        }
    }
}

class A{

}

class C : A{

}

class D{

}
```